# ReactJS Error: only absolute urls are supported

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to pull in the current URL to use in my fetch command, but I received an error when attempting to parse the URL via `window.location`. It appears that this URL use is not allowed, but I'm not sure of another alternative to achieve what I'm looking for. I'm avoiding setting a string so I can adapt my React setup to multiple environments.

**Error:**

```
Error: only absolute urls are supported
```

**Line creating the error:**

```
console.log(protocol + '//' + hostname + ':' + port + '/api' + window.location.search);
```

**Variables:**

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var protocol = window.location.protocol;
var port = window.location.port;
```

Comment: I understand you're trying to avoid setting a string, but this is why we have configuration files. It's not too egregious to set a baseURL for a given deployment.

Comment: Do you have a good resource for using env variables within ReactJS? I'm not familiar with accessing env variables with ReactJS. It sounds like this is the preferred method

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L13. At its core, you need to distinguish between the environment variables you pass to npm during the webpack building process, and the environment variables you explicitly stamp on your built assets using `webpack.DefinePlugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Then all you need to do is to create a `.env` file. There are a couple ways of loading it into your app.

**Webpack**(not the npm package listed above, instead is webpack-dotenv-plugin)

```
import DotenvPlugin from 'webpack-dotenv-plugin';
  plugins: [
    new DotenvPlugin({
      sample: './.env.default',
      path: './.env',
    }),
```

**Not webpack**

As early as possible:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```